# Mermaid and MMD in BBEdit?

Tags: bbedit, mermaid, multimarkdown

I'm a noob in scripting (for years now...) and a BBEdit fan user. I usually find solutions to my problems on StackO or GitH, but this time I do not, and I finally decide to create an account. First post on Stackoverflow ! So stressful !

BBEdit works really great for what I do. But there is 2 things I try to do and I definitively need to know if it's possible or if I change for Atom (wish do it well)... and it will be very painful. I can't stop a such love story without be absolutely sure of... I just can't write it.

So first I use a lot MD with the great Preview CSS from Ryan Dotson.

```
BBStylish – Attractive Markdown Preview CSS for BBEdit
<https://nostodnayr.net/projects/bbstylish>

Made by Ryan Dotson – rd@nostodnayr.net

Version 1
14 October 2019
```

I'm really happy with this one but it doesn't deal with tables or MMD stuffs. Is there a CCS somewhere to previewing MMD ? Or there is way to had a part of code to the Ryan Dotson CSS to do this ? I think, if I have no answer, I will ask him directly...

Secondly, is there a way to use Mermaid directly in BBEdit with a plug-in, or a CSS, or magic trick,,

Thanks a lot.
Tschüss
GG

Answer (score 1):

You can use BBEdit's "Preview Filters" feature to set up MultiMarkdown as the preferred renderer for using "Preview in BBEdit". There's pretty detailed information on how to do this, see the "Previewing Pages" section in the user manual (itself available on the Help menu).

Beginning in BBEdit 13.1 (in open beta testing at this writing, check @bbedit on Twitter for the news) you can also select the default Markdown renderer (and MultiMarkdown is an option, if you have it installed) in the Markdown language-specific preferences.